# Backlink "web" from many sites to many sites = penalty?

Tags: links, backlinks, link-building

im building several Web 2.0 properties that will have backlinks to several websites.  Each of the websites is geo-targeted to a different country and sits on that countries top level domain. And my .com will have a "choose your country" links on the home page.

I would like to have a link from each of my web2.0 properties link to each of the websites, but not vice-versa. Nor do any sites link to each other.  All links are one-way.

So this does not resemble a "link wheel" nor is it a "reciprocal link farm", but it does resemble a web of some sort.

Does this seem like something that can result in a penguin penalty, or a penalty of any kind?

[image: linkweb]

Comment: Web 2.0 links have been heavily nerfed, especially when these sites are 'NEW'. Any form of link wheel is like playing with fire, it may not hurt you at first but at some point your going to be burnt. Put away the black hat SEO books you have and look into white hat SEO that is going to make your business thrive today, tomorrow and in the future.

Comment: What is the purpose of having the wordpress, blogger, tumbler, and livejournal sites?   If you are creating them only to get links from them, then that is problematic.   If they are created because users expect you to have a presence there (users expect a Facebook presence these days), then it might be OK.

Comment: What is the anchor text of these links?   If you are using keyword anchor text on links you have created that is very problematic for Penguin.   If you are using your brand name or your domain name as your link anchor text, then it might be OK.

Comment: Some links will contain anchor text, some will be branded. But that is not my question, im well aware of Penguin.  My question is will this sort of LINK STRUCTURE trigger any sort of scrutiny regardless of anchor text. It is not a "link wheel" as non of the sites are interlinking to each other, but it is a link web and that's why im asking.

Answer (score 1):

Google looks at registration, DNS, whois, host, network, contact, citation, social, and any other information that is available and determines what sites have relationships with other sites. In addition, links are evaluated and mapped to look for linking patterns regardless of what pattern may present itself. It is an AI function and not hard-coded. Being in the business of looking at data patterns and determining relationships between network entities, I should warn you that Google has much of the same technology that the DoD and other entities concerned and charged with the nations security uses to evaluate trust networks, hack patterns, and at the very least relationships. I also warn you that this has existed for quite some time and is a well matured science. Google and security researchers share technology and new theories back and forth freely.

I would figure that Google would frown on this severely. It may take a while, but it will happen.

Once Google has seen a linking scheme pattern, it will de-list your site and your TrustRank will be in the toilet. It will take as much as a year to regain any good search traffic and even then the foundation, the TrustRank, will limit your placement for quite some time. Perhaps even years.